# ¿Cómo se dice "in the way" para expresar que estás siendo bloqueado?

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

How would you tell somebody they are "in the way"?

Like for example, too many people are in the kitchen and you want to tell somebody that they are "in the way"

Is this correct?

> Estás en el camino.

Are there other ways to say this?

Comment: Relevant meta post for questions of this sort: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1407/12

Comment: Estás en mi camino

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way of conveying that someone "is in the way" and is preventing you to access something or go somewhere is

> Estás en medio

Other way could be

> Me cierras el paso (o me estás cerrando el paso)

Comment: I would add _estás a medio camino_ or a (possibly) rude _¡estorbas!_

Comment: _A medio camino_ is not used in Spain (at least not with that meaning). I was considering "estorbas" too, but that has a broader meaning (somebody doesn't need to be in your way to _estorbar_ and usually they would do it on purpose).

Comment: No, *estás a medio camino* no es adecuado, porque eso significa que te diriges a un sitio y has recorrido la mitad del trayecto (la mitad de *lo largo* del trayecto); en cambio, cuando estás en medio, estás en la mitado de *lo ancho* del camino (de manera que no dejas pasar).

Comment: *Estorbas* es correcto, pero, como dice Diego, es más genérico y puede no referirse sólo a una cuestión *geográfica*. *Estorbar* es, más bien, sinónimo de *molestar* (*annoy* en inglés).

Comment: I didn't read these comments before writing my answer, but I do think *estorbas* is the right way to go. *Estorbar* is not exactly the same as *molestar*, as it implies blocking the way in some manner. You can *molestar* with sounds, for example, but you can only *estorbar* by being in the way.

Comment: @QOI, I disagree that ["estorbar"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=2YKqLKLloDXX2C01wmES) means only "blocking the way" and that you can only "estorbar" by being in the way. I think that there are plenty of ways to "estorbar", and not all of them involve a **physical** obstacle in front of somebody: "Tanta burocracia y papeleo es un **estorbo** a la hora de abrir un negocio; Todos esos malos recuerdos de su pasado le **estorbaban** a la hora de construir su futuro; Me fui a la otra habitación porque tanto ruido me **estorbaba** para atender la llamada".

Answer (score 3):

Sí, es:

> Estás en medio.

O:

> Estás en el medio.

*Estás en el camino* es **incorrecto** para este uso.

Ya que esto es algo muy idiomático, añado también posibles formas de pedir a alguien que deje de estar en medio.

- El verbo *apartar(se)*: *¿Puedes apartarte?* / *Aparta, por favor.* / *Aparta de ahí.* / ...
- La expresión *hacerse a un lado*: *Hazte a un lado, por favor.* / ...
- El verbo *quitar*: *¡Quita de ahí!* / *Quítate de enmedio.* / *Quita.* /...

*Quitar* y *apartar* son sinónimos en este caso, pero usarás *quitar* si eres maleducado o si estás enfadado. En caso contrario, usa las dos primeras fórmulas  (*apartar*, *hacerse a un lado*).

Comment: Decir que algo es incorrecto es algo muy fuerte y definitivo en los idiomas. Para mí _estás en el camino_ no es incorrecto. Sería mejor aclarar de dónde sos y sólo decir que ahí no se usa.

Comment: clinch, cuando he dicho que es incorrecto me refería a que lo es si quieres expresar que te está bloqueando el paso. Si dices «Estás en el camino» simplemente dices que hay un camino y que estás en él. En ningún momento se entiende que te están bloqueando el paso. Es en ese sentido que digo que es incorrecto. 

Obviamente es correcto si alguien está, en efecto, en un camino, pero si lo que quieres es expresar que no te dejan pasar tienes que cambiar la expresión. Puede ser: «Estás en el medio del camino». Ésa es, a mi entender, correcta.

Comment: Gracias. para que entiendo, es esta la traducción directa para  para Estás en medio-- "you are in the middle"?

You are in the middle is the way to express to somebody they are in the way.  I love the subtle differences in language.

Comment: @PonyVilla, no acabo de entender tu pregunta. No sé si «estás en medio» en inglés es «you are in the middle», lo que sí sé es que «you are in the way» es «estar en medio».

Comment: Creo que _incorrecto_ no es.

Answer (score 3):

The most natural way to say this in Spanish form Spain would be ***estorbas*** or ***estás estorbando***. The forms in other answers, similar to *estás en mi camino*, sound a bit forced, like what a villain would say to the hero in a movie.

Comment: This is indeed the most natural way. Other options are acceptable but those will make you sound like a movie or soap opera character.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más normal sería "estás en medio", como ya te han respondido. En Chile también se puede usar

> estás a la pasada.

Comment: Gracias. para que entiendo es la traducción directa "you are in the middle"?

Comment: in the middle = en el medio (literally)

Comment: in the way = en la vía, en el camino, a la pasada (literally)

Comment: but in real use, not literally but habitual => in the way = en medio

Comment: ¿Dónde se usa "estás a la pasada"? En España no lo he oído nunca y creo que casi nadie lo entendería.

Comment: @Gorpik: Nunca me imaginé que era una expresión regional, mil disculpas. En Chile no es que solo sea posible, es la única forma en que se dice: Por favor salgan de la pasada. Aprovecha de venir a mi casa, estoy a la pasada. Compré unos pastelitos a la pasada. Llegué atrasado porque unos caballos se pusieron a la pasada.

Comment: En general, Chile es el país latinoamericano cuya forma de hablar se parece más a la de España. Pero esta expresión no la había oído nunca. Sospecho que tampoco se usa en muchos más países; si no, supongo que alguna vez la habría oído.

Answer (score 1):

When I had a job in a restaurant we used to say: "Estoy atrás", to indicate that we had to pass but they are in front of us.

Comment: When I had I meant

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE. Don't forget that you can always edit your own posts if you need to edit something. You can also suggest edits in other users' posts, and these suggested changes will be reviewed and then approved.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are quite good, I would add that you could simply say

> Estás molestando

Context should make it clear that you're creating difficulty by being in the way

Answer (score -2):

Estás en el camino is incorrect but You could say

> usted está en mi camino

which means which is saying "you are in my way". You could do another way like,

> estás en mi manera

which also means "You are in my way"

Comment: This is not correct, *usted está en el bloqueo de mi camino* would mean *you are in the blockade of my way* or something like that, it doesn't make sense. *usted está en mi camino* is correct, tought.